# How to identify the highest normal form of a relation schema?

Tags: sql, database, normalization

Let's say we have a relation schema. How can we state the highest normal of that relation?

---

For example:

- Art_Object (Art_Id, Title, Description, Country, Artist, Epoch, Year)

Comment: You might want to consider tagging the programming language or technologies involved for a higher chance of getting an answer to your question.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to know What normal form Art_Object is in, or whether you want to know how to decompose Art_Object into higher normal forms. But in any case, normalization is based on values, not on column names, so representative sample values would be helpful. (As well as clarifying what you want.)

Comment: Just curious: shouldn't there also be a `Style` attribute? Or is it defined by `Epoch`?

Comment: i wanna know What normal form Art_Object is in? this is the test from my school. We should find this by these column.

Answer (score 3):

"i wanna know What normal form Art_Object is in? this is the test from my school."

Normal form of any given design depends on *which functional dependencies* hold.

Without being given that set of functional dependencies, the question is simply unanswerable.

If the only FD that holds is Art_ID -> {all attributes}, then your design is in 5NF.

If on the contrary there were some additional FD like Artist -> Country, then this design isn't even 3NF.

Comment: FDs, or JDs?  There's likely an FD Year ⟶ Epoch (as well as the Artist ⟶ Country FD you identify) so it is not in 3NF.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, long time no hear. Of course the operative word is "likely". The purpose of my reply was to point out exactly that.  And that there are two things wrong with this exercise : (a) the fact that the exercise relies on *assumptions* that the DB designer has to make, and (b) the fact that it is entirely left open what role the attributes such as Country play in this design (Country that was discovered by Columbus in year Year ? Country of birth of the Artist ? Country where the artpiece was created ?), making even the assumptions of (a) impossible to make.

Comment: You're right about FD/JD, of course.  But would being so precise help increase clarity, rather than confusion ?  Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned 5 NF.

Comment: It is impossible if that relation is in 5NF because i haven't learn 5NF. I think to state the highest normal form we need FD and Candidate key but no one mentioned here. IF Jonathan is right the following relation must be in BCNF: Art_Sculpture (Art_Id*, Material, Height, Weight) 
• FD: Art_Id* -------------- Material, Height, Weight
• Candidate keys: {Art_Id}
• Referential Integrity: Art_Id* reference Art_Object.Art_Id
• Normal Form: 
• Reasons: 
since Art_ID FD all of other attribute.

Comment: You said, "It is impossible if that relation is in 5NF because i haven't learn 5NF." No, it's quite possible to create relations that are in 5NF without knowing what 5NF is. Your Art_Sculpture relation is in 5NF.